# Why does std::array require the size as a template parameter and not as a constructor parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdarray

There are many design issues I have found with this, particularly with passing `std::array<>` to functions. Basically, when you initialize std::array, it takes in two template parameters, `<class T` and `size_t size>`. However, when you create a function that requires and `std::array`, we do not know the size, so we need to create template parameters for the functions also.

```
template <size_t params_size> auto func(std::array<int, params_size> arr);
```

Why couldn't `std::array` take in the size at the constructor instead? (i.e.):

```
auto array = std::array<int>(10);
```

Then the functions would look less aggressive and would not require template params, as such:

```
auto func (std::array<int> arr);
```

I just want to know the design choice for `std::array`, and why it was designed this way.

This isn't a question due to a bug, but rather a question why `std::array<>` was designed in such a manner.

Comment: If it were designed the way you wanted, it would be a `std::vector`. A different type, with different tradeoffs. There's a reason a bunch of standard library functions are written to take pairs of iterators (or, in C++20, an iterator and a sentinel) instead of a container directly.

Comment: What is "aggressive" about a template?

Comment: This is all about don't pay for what you don't use. If you don't want to pay for dynamic memory allocation then you must have a type that can do static memory allocation.  And that is std::array. It also allows you to use arrays as classes. So with this you can return them from a function, pass them by const reference. And you never loose the size of the array when passing it around (pointer decay for "C" style arrays).

Comment: To make it look less aggressive, simply replace `params_size -> N`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::array<T,N> var` is intended as a better replacement for C-style arrays `T var[N]`.

The memory space for this object is created *locally*, ie on the stack for local variables or inside the struct itself when defined as a member.

`std::vector<T>` in contrary always allocate it's element's memory in the heap.

Therefore as `std::array` is allocated locally, it cannot have a variable size since that space needs to be reserved at compile time. `std::vector` in the other hand has the ability to reallocate and resize since its memory is unbounded.

As a consequence, the big advantage of `std::array` in terms of performance is that it eliminates that one level of indirection that `std::vector` pays for its flexibility.

For example:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main() {
    int a;
    char b[10];
    std::vector<char> c(10);
    std::array<char,10> d;
    struct E {
        std::array<char,10> e1;
        std::vector<char> e2{10};
    };
    E e;

    printf( "Stack address:   %p\n", __builtin_frame_address(0));
    printf( "Address of a:    %p\n", &a );
    printf( "Address of b:    %p\n", b );
    printf( "Address of b[0]: %p\n", &b[0] );
    printf( "Address of c:    %p\n", &c );
    printf( "Address of c[0]: %p\n", &c[0] );
    printf( "Address of d:    %p\n", &d );
    printf( "Address of d[0]: %p\n", &d[0] );
    printf( "Address of e:    %p\n", &e );
    printf( "Address of e1:   %p\n", &e.e1 );
    printf( "Address of e1[0]:%p\n", &e.e1[0] );
    printf( "Address of e2:   %p\n", &e.e2);
    printf( "Address of e2[0]:%p\n", &e.e2[0] );
}
```

Produces

```
Program stdout
Stack address:   0x7fffeb115ed0
Address of a:    0x7fffeb115eb0
Address of b:    0x7fffeb115ea6
Address of b[0]: 0x7fffeb115ea6
Address of c:    0x7fffeb115e80
Address of c[0]: 0x1cad2b0
Address of d:    0x7fffeb115e76
Address of d[0]: 0x7fffeb115e76
Address of e:    0x7fffeb115e40
Address of e1:   0x7fffeb115e40
Address of e1[0]:0x7fffeb115e40
Address of e2:   0x7fffeb115e50
Address of e2[0]:0x1cad2d0
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/75s47T56f

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, really, because I *used to* despise `std::array<>` for the same reasons as you — anything with Monadic qualities are not good design (IMNSHO).

Fortunately, C++20 has the solution: a dynamic `std::span<>`.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

namespace detail
{
  void print( const std::span<const int> & xs )
  {
    for (size_t n = 0;  n < xs.size();  n++)
      std::cout << xs[n] << " ";
  }
}

void print( const std::span<const int> & xs )
{
  std::cout << "{ ";
  detail::print( xs );
  std::cout << "}\n";
}

void add( const std::span<int> & xs, int n )
{
  for (int & x : xs)
    x += n;
}

int main()
{
  std::array<int,5> xs { 1, 2, 4, 6, 10 };
  add( xs, 1 );
  print( xs );
}
```

Notice that the `span` itself is `const` in all cases, but the elements themselves are modifiable unless they too are tagged `const`. This is exactly what an array is like.

`std::span` is a C++20 object. I know that MS and maybe others had a `array_view` in older versions of their libraries.

**tl;dr**
Use `std::array` only to declare your array object. Pass it around with a dynamic `std::span`.

---

#### std::array vs C array

The use-case for `std::array` is actually very narrow: encapsulate a *fixed-size* array as a first-class container object (one that can be copied, not just referenced).

At first blush this doesn’t seem to be much of an improvement over standard C-style arrays:

```
typedef int myarray[10];             // (1)
using myarray = std::array<int,10>;  // (2)

void f( myarray a );
```

But it is! The difference is in what `f()` actually gets:

1. For a C-style array, the argument is just a pointer — a reference to the caller’s data (that you can modify!). You know the size of the referenced array (`10`), but writing code to get that size is not straight-forward even with the usual C array-size idiom (`sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(a[0])`, since `sizeof(a)` is the size of a pointer).
2. For the `std::array`, the argument value is an actual *local copy* of the caller’s data. If you want to be able to modify the caller’s data then you need to be explicit about declaring the formal argument as a reference type (`myarray & a`) or just to avoid an expensive copy (`const myarray & a`). This falls in line with how other C++ objects are passed. And though the size is still `10`, your code can query the size of the array with the usual C++ container idiom: `a.size()`!

The usual way C overcomes this is to clutter the call site and formal argument lists with information about the array size so that it doesn’t get lost.

```
int f( int array[], size_t n )   // traditional C
{
  printf( "There are %zu elements.\n", n );
  recurse with f( array, n );
}

int main(void)
{
  int my_array[10];
  f( my_array, ARRAY_SIZE(my_array) );
```

The `std::array` way is cleaner.

```
int f( std::array<int,10> & array )   // C++
{
  std::cout << "There are " << array.size() << " elements.\n";
  recurse with f( array );
}

int main()
{
  std::array<int,10> my_array;
  f( my_array );
```

But while cleaner, it is significantly less flexible than the C array, simply because its length is *fixed*. A caller cannot pass a `std::array<int,12>` to the function, for example.

I’ll refer you to the other good answers here to consider more about container choice when handling arrayed data.

Comment: That was a good read. I do not use std::span yet but will once c++20 becomes mainstream.

Comment: Sometimes, one needs to make a copy, especially through a function argument. Introducing a new type is not the solution IMO, also `std::span` has screwed up semantics, broken constness, etc. Ah, also don't use `std::span` in any other place that is not a function argument. It is too problematic for my taste. I think it only solves the problem of having a stable ABI for contiguous memory, but it is bad for generic programming.

Comment: I am curious about "anything with Monadic qualities are not good design". how is `std::array`? even if so, why would it be bad design?

Comment: @alfC In a pure language like Haskell, monads are used to manage things like I/O without introducing side effects. The problem is that they contaminate everything all the way down the call chain: transferring the impurity from a side effect into the structure of the program. `std::array` does the same thing, exchanging clunky syntax and a clean solution to clean syntax and a clunky/bloated solution. The root problem is that arrays have never been first-class citizens when they very easily could have been. But this late in the game the technical hurdles are too weird & arcane to fix in C & C++.

Comment: I don't see the parallel since I don't know enough about Haskell or about monads to judge. But I can't see anything more functional than returning a pure value, and std::array (of a given T and N) is a pure value. You can't return T[N] or std::span, and even if you could these two will not be pure values but references to external values.

Comment: @alfC Span is a pointer type.  It has correct constness for a pointer type.  Treating it as a container will get you confused, but if you don't, it makes sense.  (it does block assignment to deal with people who treat it like a container, admittedly).  More importantly, span directly solves some of the OP's problems, and this solution describes how to us it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Well, it is a const pointer at best because it is not assignable. It is also a pointer without a concrete value type! (It can't have a pointer trait). The argument doesn't go that far in the actual environment also: the problem is that `std::array` which is (arguably) a container (value) gets converted (and implicitly!) to what you say is a pointer. See the problem, values that convert into their own pointers! This is terrible for generic programming,. BTW, there is an obvious true pointer out there `std::array<int,  5>*` to begin with.

Comment: Actually, I’m done here.

Comment: @alfC Sure?  So call it a reference with barred assignment.  In any case, range views are a known thing at this point, and they are very useful.  If your generic programming technique doesn't handle it, update your generic programming.  There are conventions to detect things, such as concepts, if you need to distinguish.  I'm sorry evolution of convention seems to be causing you such angst.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont mmm, it is a reference or a pointer? both? Don't get me wrong, I think it solves a technical problem, and one may get away if all is const (`span<T const> const`). C++ concepts can help to a point if the *C*oncept makes sense. const correctness is the first victim of this ambiguity. I am not the only one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCIKbUvEKfI&t=2461s , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8HndvYNvQ4 . Also, other designs are possible https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi#const-correctness. https://github.com/josuttis/belleviews

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem with `std::array` and you think `std::span` is a  solution, now you will have **two** problems.

More seriously, without knowing what kind of conceptual operation is `func` it is difficult to tell what is the right alternative.

First, if you want or can exploit to know the size at compile-time there is nothing cooler than what you are trying to avoid.

```
template<std::size_t N> 
void func(std::array<int, N> arr);   // add & or && or const& if appropiate
```

Imagine it, knowing the size at compile time can allow you **and** the compiler to do all sorts of tricks, like unrolling loops completely or verifying logic at compile time (e.g. if you know the size must be smaller or bigger than a constant).
Or the coolest trick of all, not needing to allocate memory for any auxiliary operation inside `func` (because you know the size of the problem a priori).

If you want a dynamic array, use (and pass) a `std::vector`.

```
void func(std::vector<int> dynarr);   // add & or && or const& if appropiate
```

But then you force your caller to use `std::vector` as the container.

If you want a fixed array, and it will work with everything,

```
template<class FixedArray>
void func(FixedArray dynarr);   // add & or && or const& if appropiate
```

Ask yourself, how specific is your function such that you really really want to make it work with **any** size of `std::array` but not with `std::vector`?
Why specifically `int`s even?

```
template<class ArithmeticRange>
void func(ArithmeticRange dynarr);   // add & or && or const& if appropiate
```

Comment: I'd have the first example be `void func(std::array<int, 3> arr);`, and then go on to the `template <size_t N>` version

Comment: @Caleth, I don't understand your comment, are you explaining the OP logic?

Comment: No, I'm saying the OP has missed the very relevant case where you do know the size from the start

Comment: @Caleth, yes, I realize that "knowing" is a tricky concept for people coming from interpreted languages, especially when transitioning to languages that can metaprogram. One can "know" things at runtime but not at compile-time or coding-time, or one can "know" things at runtime and at compile-time but not at coding-time, etc.

Comment: Taking a dynamically allocated buffer by value seems like a big step to take.  Every other solution above requires templates code generation, which have code size, compile time and dependency issues in anything beyond small projects.  What more, the entire algorithm is templated, not just a small piece, which can make the problem a lot worse.  Compilers *can* inline stuff like "size of an array" if they want to; templates practically force the compiler to do so.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, as I put in the inline comments "add `&` as necessary". Without knowing the application I don't know if he/she needs it or not. I could have written `&&` all over but I didn't want to  distract from the main point.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few contiguous containers and ranges in C++ `std`.  They serve different purposes.  There are also a few techniques for passing them around.

I'll try to be exhaustive.

```
std::array<int, 7>
```

this is a buffer of 7 `int`s.  They are stored within the object itself.  Putting an `array` somewhere is putting enough storage for exactly `7` `int`s in that location (plus possible padding for alignment reasons, but that is at the end of the buffer).

You use this when, at compile time, you know exactly how big something is, or need to know.

```
std::vector<int>
```

this object holds ownership of a buffer of `int`s.  The memory that holds those `int`s is dynamically allocated and can change at runtime.  The object itself is usually 3 pointers in size.  It has some strategies to grow that avoids doing N^2 work when you keep adding 1 element at a time to it.

This object can be efficiently moved -- it will steal the buffer if the old object is marked (by `std::move` or other ways) as being safe to steal state from.

```
std::span<int>
```

This represents an externally owned sequence of `int`s, possibly stored in a `std::array` or owned by a `std::vector`, or stored somewhere else.  It knows where in memory it starts and when it ends.

Unlike the two above, it is *not* a container, but a range or a view of the contents.  So you can't assign spans to each other (the semantics are confusing), and you are responsible to ensure that the source buffer lasts "long enough" that you don't use it after it is gone.

`span` is often used as a function argument.  In your case, it probably solves most of your problem -- it lets you pass arrays of different sizes to a function, and within that function you can read or write the values.

`span` followed pointer semantics.  That means `const std::span<int>` is like a `int*const` -- the *pointer* is `const`, but the thing pointed to is not!  You are free to modify the elements in `const std::span<int>`.  In comparison, `std::span<const int>` is like a `int const*` -- the pointer is not const, but the thing pointed to is.  You are free to change what range of elements the span refers to in `std::span<const int>`, but you aren't allowed to modify the elements themselves.

A final technique is `auto` or templates.  Here we implement the body of the function in the header (or equivalent) and leave the type unconstrained (or, constrained by concepts).

```
template<std::size_t N>
int total0( std::array<int, N> const& elems ) {
  int r = 0;
  for (int e:elems) r+=e;
  return r;
}

int total1( std::vector<int> const& elems ) {
  int r = 0;
  for (int e:elems) r+=e;
  return r;
}

int total2( std::span<int const> elems ) {
  int r = 0;
  for (int e:elems) r+=e;
  return r;
}

int total3( auto const& elems ) {
  int r = 0;
  for (int e:elems) r+=e;
  return r;
}

template<class Ints>
int total4( Ints const& elems ) {
  int r = 0;
  for (int e:elems) r+=e;
  return r;
}
```

notice these all have the same implementation.

`total3` and `total4` are identical; you need a more modern compiler to use `total3` syntax.

`total1` and `total2` allow you to split the implementation into a cpp file away from the header file.  Also, code generation isn't done for different arguments.

`total0`, `total3` and `total4` all result in different code to be generated based on the type of the arguments.  This can cause binary bloat issues, especially if the body was more complex than shown, and causes build time problems in larger projects.

`total1` won't work with a `std::array` directly.  You can do `total1({arr.begin(), arr.end()})` which would copy the contents to a dynamic vector before using the code.

Finally, note that `span<int>` is the closest you get to the C way of `arr[], size`.  Span is, in essence, a pointer-to-first and length pair, with utility code wrapping it.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of a C++11 `std::array<>` is to be a decent replacement for C-style arrays `[]`, especially when they're declared with `new` and dismissed with `delete[]`.

The main goal here is to get an official, managed object that serves as an array, while maintaining as constant expressions everything that can be.

Principal issues with regular arrays is that since they're not actually objects, one cannot derivate a class from them (forcing you to implement iterators) and are a pain when you copy classes that uses them as object properties.

Since `new`, `delete` and `delete[]` return pointers, you need each time either to implement a copy constructor that will declare another array them copy its content or maintaining your own dynamic reference counter on it.

From this perpective, `std::array<>` is a good way to declare purely static arrays that will be managed by the language itself.

Comment: No. that would be std::vector. std::array is a wrapper for raw/native arrays that are not dynamically allocated. That is when new is _not_ used to create the array, but it has a fixed compile time size.

Comment: This is what I explained. Read again, please. The purpose of this comment was to tell why `std::array<>` have been introduced this way and what were their use, compared to vectors that were already existing in precedent standard versions.

Comment: _"std::array<> . . . replacement for C-style arrays [], especially when they're declared with new"_ `std::array<>` is fixed size known at compile time. new/delete provide for dynamically allocated arrays with size determined at run-time, not compile-time (and can only be managed via pointer, not directly. `std::array<>` _cannot_ be used as a replacement for a run-time sized array; that is the job of std::vector. Also native/raw arrays as class members copy just fine. (Pointers to dynamically allocated arrays are another matter, but arrays are not pointers.)